# Go through every pixel of an image

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I recently started working with images in java.
I want to implement a basic motion-tracking system based on colors (I know that this won't be very efficient, but it is just for testing).

Right now I want to process an image in Java.
I want to delete all Colors in a RGB image instead of one or instead of a range of colors.

Right now I haven't found a good solution. I want it to keep it as simple an possible and try not to use any other libraries than the standard ones of Java.

Comment: What have you found so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the BufferedImage (standard image class in java), you have two "good" solutions to access the pixels.

1 - Using the raster, easier because it automatically handles the encoding, but it is slower.

```
WritableRaster wr = image.getRaster() ;
for (int y=0, nb=0 ; y < image.getHeight() ; y++)
    for (int x=0 ; x < image.getWidth() ; x++, nb++)
        {
        int r = wr.getSample(x, y, 0) ; // You just give the channel number, no need to handle the encoding.
        int g = wr.getSample(x, y, 1) ;
        int b = wr.getSample(x, y, 2) ;
        }
```

2 - Using the DataBuffer, fastest because direct access to the pixels, but YOU have to handle the encoding.

```
switch ( image.getType() )
    {
    case BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR : // Classical color images encoding.
        byte[] bb = ((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;
        for (int y=0, pos=0 ; y < image.getHeight() ; y++)
            for (int x=0 ; x < image.getWidth() ; x++, pos+=3)
                {
                int b = bb[pos] & 0xFF ;
                int g = bb[pos+1] & 0xFF ;
                int r = bb[pos+2] & 0xFF ;
                }
        break ;
    }
```

getRGB() is easy but much slower and not easier than the raster, so just ban it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you change your mind and consider using some image processing library:

**Motion Regions**
http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/examples/motionRegions.html
[image]

**Pong Game**
http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/examples/pongGame.html
[image]